# Visual C# template missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates

I am missing multiple templates but for only one project from a Github repository in Visual Studio. Whenever I got to 'Add' < 'New Item' and try to add a new class to the project I only see AspNetCore under the installed tab and not the usual Visual C# for classes etc. I am unsure on what to do as all of my other projects that I created myself locally have all the templates I need.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was download .NET SDK version 2.0 and all the necessary templates appeared.